# Cannot query by using variable but using hard code is working

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to do query in mongoose like this,

```
    var startDate = Number(new Date('2016-01-15T14:20:24.491Z'));
    var endDate = Number(new Date('2016-01-15T14:20:24.506Z'));
    console.log(endDate); // result is 1452842424506
    console.log(startDate); // result is 1452842424491
    var criteria = {
      timeStamp : {
        $lte : endDate.toString(),
        $gte : startDate.toString()
      }
    };
    Touchpoint.find().where(criteria).exec(function(err, data){
      reply(data);
    });
```

It will always return an empty result. But When I do hard code like this

```
    var criteria = {
      timeStamp : {
        $lte : '1452842424506',
        $gte : '1452842424491'
      }
    };
```

It work !!

I don't really understand what is wrong with my startDate and endDate variable.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a string before placing it on the object?

Comment: The value of startDate in your first example `var startDate = Number(new Date('2016-01-15T14:20:24.491Z'));` is actually 1452867624491, not 1452842424491. If you compare the strings several of the characters are different, which is probably why the results are different.